# Magento 2: Backup failed, Error received from server

Tags: magento2, permissions, backup, file-permissions

I try to install an extension and can't continue because my backup failed:

```
Backup failed
Error received from server:
```

I setup file permission like this for shared hosting but it didn't help:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

[image: Screenshot of error]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7LoR.png)

Answer (score 0):

What I did was backing up manually and continue.

Comment: Need to download the entire root folder from file manger of cpanel & unzip it with 7-zip software your problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

From the Magento root directory run:

```
php bin/magento support:utility:paths
```

This will generate `var/support/Paths.php` file and solve this error.

Comment: Prints InvalidArgumentException.
I have to mention that in my case backup files are created and stored in var/backups successfully, despite the error message.

Comment: How long does it run before it fails? You could be hitting some sort of php script execution timeout limit if you have not configured it beyond the defaults in /etc/php.ini and php-fpm...

Comment: limit is set to 18000 in php.in aswell as in .htaccess. double checked to increase the limit in the correct php.ini. Still fails after about one minute more or less.